# Fourier transform before calculating the phase

Tags: image-processing

When and why do we need to perform Fourier transform before calculating the [phase](https://robotics.eecs.berkeley.edu/~sastry/ee20/vision2/node6.html) of the image?

Comment: Can you define "phase of an image"?

Comment: @MBaz i have edited the question.

Comment: The phase is derived by the [Fourier Transform](https://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/fourier.htm). Can you please clarify the question?

Answer (score 2):

The discrete Fourier transform (DFT) does by definition transform your image into the frequency domain, mapping it to a matrix of complex numbers.

Again, by definition, a complex number has a phase and a magnitude component.

Thus, you don't "need to perform FT before calculating the phase of an image", you **get the phase of the image as a result of the FT**.

It's a bit like saying "why do I need to perform an addition before calculating the sum of 2 number?".

I would suggest you to learn more about Fourier Transform

Comment: could you please check this [link](http://matlabgeeks.com/tips-tutorials/how-to-do-a-2-d-fourier-transform-in-matlab/)  , they performed FT before calculating the phase.